# Can Macs be put in hibernation voluntarily?

Tags: macos, hibernate

I know that when you put your Mac laptop to sleep and the battery dies, next time you plug it in it will wake up from the state it was prior to being put to sleep. There are also hacks to get this behavior with a desktop Mac (except it triggers when you put the Mac to sleep and unplug it).

Is there a way to trigger this behavior without cutting power, and that will still let me put my Mac to sleep normally? Like Windows 7's Hibernate option.

Comment: Damn. I thought I could use this to switch between OS X and Windows efficiently, but the boot loader won't let you boot on anything else than Mac OS if it's been put in hibernation.

Comment: I think for you it's better to use parallels Desktop. it's really good software and make you able to boot your install windows on your mac.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: I already have VMWare Fusion, that I use for work-related stuff. The reason I want to boot my machine on Windows is to play Starcraft 2, because performances on OS X are far below those of Windows.

Comment: I am glad you plat Starcraft II, I am a big fan of blizzard too but I get starcraft for OS X and don't have your problem :P

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: it's totally playable under OS X for sure. However, with my current-gen MacBook Pro under Windows I can put the game in 1680x1050 with graphics somewhere above medium and still get a smooth 60+ frames per second, and it never drops below that. Under Mac OS, with the same settings, things aren't smooth. So it's good for you if you like Starcraft II under Mac OS, but until Apple or NVidia or whoever's responsible does some serious efforts at making the graphics drivers better, I'll play it under Windows because there is a very noticeable difference.

Comment: The reason the bootloader will not let you boot into something else when there is a hibernate image is that the hibernated version of the kernel may have references to blocks on the disk, and if you boot into another OS it wouldn't know that, which means it could modify the disk. When the hibernated OS was thawed it would then potentially write out its dirty buffers to the disk on top of blocks that had already been modified, leading to disk corruption. Fundamentally, it is never safe to thaw a hibernation if there is a chance the filesystem it is rooted off has been modified.

Comment: @Louis Gerbarg: I didn't think about that (probably because Windows can't write to Mac OS files), but that seems like a good reason.

Comment: There are 3rd party Windows drivers that can read and write HFS+, as can Linux, or a second OS X install. The firmware doesn't know what will happen once it boots the OS, all it can tell is whether or not it is booting off the same partition it booted off the last time.

Comment: @Louis Gerbarg: Yeah, I know that. It should have read "My Windows installation".

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks/1573#1573

Comment: @Nippysaurus Thank you, but this question is about 3 weeks older than the answer you point to.

Comment: I've done some research on this. Check it out here:
http://superuser.com/questions/432838/hibernate-between-os-x-and-bootcamp-win-7

Comment: @zneak — Three weeks older, so what ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. I myself use [Deep Sleep widget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/status/deepsleep.html) (second [link](http://deepsleep.free.fr/)) to put my Macbook Pro into hibernation.

And if you prefer to use the command line, read this [article](http://macsimplelife.blogspot.com/2007/11/mac-os-x-hibernate-issue.html).

[image]

Comment: The "of course you can" part seems to imply there is a simple, built-in way to do what the OP asked.  But the main answer is a third party solution.  Perhaps the main command from the link should be posted here to comply with "[Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)."

Answer (score 14):

You could use [DeepSleep](http://www.axoniclabs.com/DeepSleep/).

I know this is a widget, but if you want an application, do the following :

1. Download the widget and uncompress the zip file containing it, but do **not** install it.
2. Right-click on the widget, the select *Show Package Contents*.

   > [image: right click]
3. Copy the *DeepSleep* Application where you want.

   > [image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a pref pane called [smart sleep](http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html) that is pretty good