# How do I select a file or directory inside a package?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

When an application pops up the Mac OS X standard file or directory chooser dialog it won't allow me to open packages so that I can select something within.  Is there a way to do this without creating a symbolic link to the target?

For a specific example: I've installed Komodo Edit & the Python SDK for Google App Engine.  In Komodo's Language > Python preferences I can add Python import directories to help with syntax checking or debugging.  The GAE libraries are in `/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine` but I can't navigate there using the directory chooser.

(I'm not asking how to browse the contents of a package from the Finder or command line.)

Comment: Thanks for the tag Am1rr3zA; I wanted to add 'package' but it's new, as am I...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the Finder to navigate inside the bundle, and then drag and drop the file to the 'Open file' dialog/sheet.

See a more visual explanation [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks/774#774).

Comment: Great answer.  I'm using this all the time now, this used to frustrate the hell out of me.

Answer (score 9):

From the dialog, use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. This will open a small 'Go to folder' dialog where you can type (or paste) the path that you want including paths within packages.

Comment: Typing worked but pasting didn't - so I think Carmine's answer is better, though it's good to know about this anyway.