# How to create a shortcut on the desktop to a selected folder

Tags: keyboard, desktop, folders, alias

In windows when right clicking a folder there is an option: send to -> desktop (create shortcut).

How can I do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 4):

1. Start automator
2. Make new service
3. Set it to receive files and folders in finder
4. add the 'new aliases' command
5. it's set to desktop by default
6. save the service as 'send alias to desktop' and voila!

Now you have an extra option under the right click menu, and a service in the finder menu!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can simply drag the folder to the desktop while holding the <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd> keys…

If your windows are so cluttered that it is inconvenient, just make sure your Desktop icon is showing in the "Places" location on the [Finder sidebar](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/dock-and-finder.html), and drag the item while holding <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd> to that icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag the [proxy icon](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks/442#442) onto the desktop to create a shortcut.