# Invoke QuickLook in Open/Save dialogue windows

Tags: macos

A handy tip I discovered by accident.

Highlight any file in an Open/Save window, press the space bar and voila! there is your file in all it's glory.

Comment: This belongs as an answer in the [Mac OS X hidden features and nice tips and tricks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks) thread. Please post it there. Thanks.

Comment: New to this, thanks for the help, just posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

Well thank you! :D
This will certainly be useful.

Just as a note to everyone who sees this, it apparently only works on the window, not on the dropdown. I cant get the quicklook in the Save As dialogue.