# Is there any way to get rid of the sound made when a screenshot is created?

Tags: audio, screen-capture

Obviously other than muting the computer. I just want to create a screenshot without having that "camera sound" come out.

Is there a way to disable this sound?

Answer (score 8):

After launching Grab, open preferences (in the menus, click Grab => Preferences) and uncheck "Enable Sound".

A screenshot of the preferences here:

[image]

Comment: WOW. I didn't even realize Grab was actually still relevant. I remember using it until I learned of the Keyboard Shortcuts, but to think that it's preference still drives the entire built-in facility? Wow! +1 (and much more if I could!). P.S. You should seriously post that to the [Tips and Tricks](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks) question. Totally worth it.

Comment: Under Snow Leopard, this disabled the screen-shot sound only in Grab.  It had no effect on the built-in screen-shot (Cmd-Shift-4).

Comment: This doesn't work on 10.8 either (for non-Grab captures). So @Jason, it would seem it actually isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off user interface sounds, though that will remove the empty trash sound and the like.

[image]

I havent tried it, but the file itself resides at `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/Resources/SystemSounds/system/Grab.aif`, you might try moving that temporarily and seeing if you can screenshot still.