# Are there any way I can have a Dashboard Widget visible all the time on the desktop?

Tags: dashboard-widget

A thing that I like with Windows 7 is that I can have the gadgets (widgets) open and visible all the time, e.g. a small RSS reader in the corner of the desktop.

I would like to be able to have a small RSS reader in the corner of my Mac OS X desktop too. I already use a RSS reader as Dashboard widget, but I have to press `F12` every time I want to chek it. Are there any way I can show the widgets all the time while I'm working in other applications? I haven't used the Dashboard that much before.

Comment: I suggest you follow http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/mac-os-x-hidden-features-and-nice-tips-tricks/401#401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag a widget outside the "screen" it appears in, if you enable the debugging mode for the Dashboard.

- Open a Terminal window, and execute the following command: `defaults write com.apple.dashboard devmode YES`
- log out, and log in back
- press the key-combination that in your Mac shows the Dashboard
- grab the widget you want to take off from the Dashboard, and drag it
- press the key-combination that you used to make the Dashboard appear
- drop the widget when you want to place it

Alternatively, there are some utilities that enable it for you; I cannot report you which ones are, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out GeekTool.  There are some geeklets available to show an RSS feed on your desktop and are relatively easy to set up if you do a bit of reading.

You can download GeekTool from here -> http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/

Geeklets -> http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/geeklets/about/