# How do I enable fine volume control via a keyboard shortcut in Lion?

Tags: macos, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is fine volume adjustment possible in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19146/is-fine-volume-adjustment-possible-in-os-x-lion)

Is there a way to re-enable the fine volume control using

```
shift + option + volume
```

It has been removed in Lion, but I use it often.
Maybe there is a `globals` pref that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do some modifications & scripting to get the effect.

See instructions here: http://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/jrgxx/how_to_quarter_step_volume_adjustment_in_lion/

Comment: I linked to the instructions because as far as I know (some people have tried) there is no other way to do this.