# Change volume range for sound? (i.e. dB-range for slider)

Tags: macos, audio, sound-volume

I have an issue where the "slider" for volume is near unusable for a USB-headset. Only the first four mini-steps (see [Lowest volume is still too loud—how can I make it even lower?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63253/lowest-volume-is-still-too-loud-how-can-i-make-it-even-lower)) are somehow valid volume ranges, the rest are way too high.

In the MIDI-control I can see that the dB-range is from -37 dB (0-volume) to -0 dB (1-volume, or max, the scale is between 0 and 1). With mini-steps (see above) the increment is 0.016-volume, but the first step from 0 to 0.016 gets the dBs from -37 to -32.37, and each following mini-step is roughly 0.5 dBs closer to 0.

**I want the volume slider to step between -37 and -18 dBs** instead of -32.37 (the lowest mini-step with sound) to 0. Is this doable somehow **using the normal vol up / vol down keys**?

As a comment, I think the actual dB-values are way off, but that probably depends on the fact that it is a USB-headset.

**Edit**
Added image below, note that this is set manually, I cannot get it this low with volume keys. Lowest with volume keys is "value" at 0.016 and db at -32.37, whilst I'd like 0.001 and db at -36 as I have now (via applescript).

[image: Image of Audio MIDI Setup]

Comment: macOS version?  USB-headset make/model?

Comment: @Allan 10.12.6 now, have had the problem since 10.11.3 at least. Corsair Vengeance 1500. I fail to see the relevance of that though, since I'm not interested in this particular headset, but what to do with OSX when the volume ranges are messed up, or just not shifted right for you.

Comment: May the solution involve an application running in the background?

Comment: @oa- Ofc, as long as I can use the normal vol up / vol down functionality.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the Audio MIDI Setup window while your USB-headset is connected and set to the highest acceptable volume?

Comment: Here's an old answer that may work, I've never tried and don't have my Mac at the moment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63253/lowest-volume-is-still-too-loud-how-can-i-make-it-even-lower

Comment: @theeelshaveeyes Tried that, even referencing it in my question :-)

Comment: @oa- Added image

Answer (score 1):

I also had this Problem a years ago by then I found no way to do it with OS X Onboard Tools didn't even try nor know the AppleScript Workaround (this would have been enough for me i think) anyway.

My Solution I ended Up using was to use Soundflower https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/ a Software based 2 or 64 Channel Audiorouting Tool.

Maybe it also had some inpact on my decision to use it that I already used it for Music Production.

I think the Way I used it to do what you're looking for was as follows:

Soundflower shows up as 2 Separate Audio Devices on the Audio-Midi-Setup a 2Channel and a 64Channel Device both with individual Soundlevel Sliders.

So I just set the System Out under Systemsettings to Soundflower 2Channel and then set a Audio Level on the Soundflower 2Channel Device.

By that time Soundflower was a free Tool don't know if its still free and also am not 100% shure if I really only used Soundflower back then or together with Jack http://www.jackosx.com.

As I said it was years ago and I can't remember all exactly also I now have different Audio Setup much more complex so i'm currently not able to try it out by myself.

Hope it still helps you.