# How to rescale macOS output volume to be quieter

Tags: macos, audio, big-sur, sound-volume

My headphones are too loud for me. How can I resize macOS' volume control so that max volume is only 30% of the actual possible power output?

And then I have fine control within the 0-30% range.

At the moment, 1 pixel from mute is still too loud in some environments.

Comment: Related: [Lowest volume is still too loud—how can I make it even lower?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63253/lowest-volume-is-still-too-loud-how-can-i-make-it-even-lower) (not a duplicate, IMHO, since the current question is asking for a different solution)

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/use-headphone-audio-level-features-iph64ac7296f

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a software solution for this on current macOS versions (there are/were solutions up to macOS 10.15; they are likely using kernel extensions and thus don't work on macOS 11+), but you can solve it with hardware:

Search for "headphones volume control adapter". These are adapters you plug in between your Mac and you headphones which can lower the volume.