# How can I replicate Windows End/Home key?

Tags: keyboard

How can I replicate Windows Home/End keys to use to jump to the end of a line or use Shift to highlight to the end or start of a line

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I used the following a lot.

<kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ꜛ</kbd>: Home

<kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>: End

<kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>: Beginning of Line

<kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>: End of Line

These I learned the other day from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/got-any-mac-os-x-hidden-features-or-nice-tips-tricks) - very handy for coding and writing, these are emacs bindings which work on Macs.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: beginning of line.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: end of line.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: delete from cursor to beginning of line.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: delete from cursor to end of line.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: erase word to the left.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: transpose characters around cursor.

Answer (score 4):

The shortcuts you're looking for are listed on this very handy [article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343) in the Apple KB. Hope it helps.

Comment: Extensive. This is handy.

Answer (score 4):

With MacBook Air (the 2012 model at least) the best solution I found was [the free KeyRemap4MacBook utility](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) -- it lets you change the keyboard in many ways, and I settled with "fn + cursor left/right" for Home/End and "fn + up/down" for PgUp/PgDown.

(See also a [related question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40320/how-to-assign-to-the-home-key-the-action-go-to-the-start-of-line-globally) with the same answer.)

Comment: Concise, clearly-written answer, with research on related answers, well done. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks @gosmond, it it quite fun to learn the Mac after 20 years on PC keyboard :)

Answer (score 2):

These can actually be mapped globally for most applications by creating entries in `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`

But this guy created [a handy little packaged script called Keyfixer](http://www.starryhope.com/tech/apple/2006/keyfixer/) that sets up the bindings in the way you describe (with some additional Control and Shift modifiers.) I threw it in my Dropbox and run it on any Mac I have to use. Since the preferences are per-user you don't have to worry about screwing up someone else's keys.