# How to assign to the "home" key the action "Go to the start of line" Globally

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard

Is there a way in which I can replicate the Windows way of going to the start of line by using <kbd>home</kbd> and not <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> ?

I did it in Eclipse, but I'd rather do it globally. I'm using Snow Leopard 10.6.8

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a third party application, [KeyRemap4Macbook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) can do it for you (and a whole lot more too).

[image: KeyRemap4Macbook]

Comment: No i don't mind, tomorrow i'll give it a try!