# What un(der)-documented features have you stumbled upon in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos

This question serves to share and collect the enhancements **which are not documented by Apple, or documented poorly.**

Please justify your answer; if it is something that is well documented by Apple and elsewhere on the web, it does not belong here. Your answer should put the feature into context, explaining how to use it. Add a [picture](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/taking-screenshots-is-a-snap/) if necessary.

Please add **only one topic per answer**. *Try to find and edit existing features / answers rather than posting a duplicate answer which will end up getting deleted. Note that answers which are not specific to Mountain Lion will be removed as well. You can post such answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-mac-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks).*

Comment: I wish I had enough rep on Apple.SE to downvote.  As it is, you'll have to make do with an angry glare: ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @GnomeSlicE That makes me ಥ_ಥ. If you don't like the wording you can edit it. If that's not enough, you'll have to wait.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just think it's not a very good question for the Q&A format of the site.  No amount of editing will change that, in my opinion.

Comment: @GnomeSlicE We've done these type of wiki collections several times in the past. While they are disputed, they always receive a lot of resonance. It's better to avoid them, especially for little things. But as *Apple does not document everything they introduce in their software* this question can be useful to many. Feel free to discuss these type of questions on meta.

Comment: Disagree with GnomeSlicE. Agree with gentmatt. These types of questions, when well cultivated, can be very useful and discourage (to some extent) the really bad CW posts.

Comment: The 200+ improvements mentioned by Apple can be found at http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html

Comment: Ars Technica has an [in depth review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/). Check the TOC

Comment: @gent provided you are VERY STRICT about the "is not documented anywhere else and definitely not by Apple" requirement. The danger is that this turns into an "infinite list of opinions about X", so the criteria need to be strict enough that is prevented from happening.

Comment: To that end, 13 out of 17 answers are [documented on the page Hope4You linked](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html). The ones that aren't are [Exposé for all windows](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57365/6703), the [AppleScriptability of Messages](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57376/6703) (something all built-in OS X apps have), [WPA2 support for internet sharing](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57488/6703), and [zoom for PDFs in Quick Look](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57495/6703) cc: @JeffAtwood

Comment: @MarkTrapp Far too many Apple apps have either no AppleScript support or utterly trivial AppleScript support. Messages having a real Event Handler Script is a big deal.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Yes, just because it's documented elsewhere means that it can't possibly exist as an answer on a Stack Exchange question...

Comment: @jason 38 answers and counting... Stack Exchange does *not* exist to merely duplicate information that is available elsewhere, and present it as a poll. For example the "How Things Work" beta site ended up as little more than reformatting content that was elsewhere on the web, and was shut down as a result. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15025/how-things-work

Comment: @JeffAtwood As of now the requirement for answers is not limited to undocumented features. This makes sense as some features are only found hidden in support documents or blog posts. The *average user* - who is targeted by this site - will surely not go through all of these documentations himself. So this Wiki does also serve this specific purpose. However, if the SE network does not want to support this, I think we should start to clean up AskDifferent in general and define a more strick FAQ for the future.

Comment: @JeffAtwood This is one question. There are a handful like it (as compared to the number of non-CW questions on the site). One large question surely has better odds than an entire site.

Comment: @gent undocumented or *under* documented. I just want there to be some rational, objective criteria for answers here other than "I like to type this on the web page."

Comment: @JeffAtwood Ok, I understand and I also like your adjustments in the latest edit of the question.

Comment: @GnomeSlicE totally disagree, It might not fit the Q&A format for the SE *network*, but for *this* site, it fits great, and when a big product launch happens, we get to create a sort of peer reviewed list of cool things that interest our members.  Indeed most of the active and certainly all time participants here take part in these CWs.  It's not simply a case of redocumenting existing material, it's a way of presenting those bits which we find most interesting or useful.  We rarely have CWs, perhaps someone can quantify what %age are, but the ones we do have are usually welcome by our users.

Comment: @JeffAtwood There are only [78 open community wiki questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1+closed%3A0) on AD (thanks to Jason for pointing that out), which is an average of 39 a year. I went through them and many of them are highly upvoted questions that have many good answers. I have gone through many of these CW questions (in particular, the Lion CW) and gained much new information from just browsing through answers.

Comment: I guess my point was that this question can't possibly generate a single 'accepted' answer.  It reads more like a forum.

Comment: @GnomeSlice CW was developed for... exactly this reason in the first place! Jeff is grumbly because the feature was abused ad nauseum due to the scale of Stack Overflow. Something that really isn't as proportionally relevant here. What's good for SO is good for SE, or something like that.

This discussion should probably go to meta...

Comment: @GnomeSlice That's why it's not a question, it's a Community Wiki post.  We did some maths in the chat room, reckon we are running at about 0.4% questions that operate like this, and even that is skewed because there used to be more, there have only been 3 or 4 this year - and Jeff has even posted answer to them in the past...

Comment: ...apart from Apple removing the "hours" from the battery icon, and making years of archived RSS feeds unaccessible? :-( (Okay, the RSS is still on my disk; no idea how to convert that though.)

Answer (score 47):

You can now silence bouncing application icons in the Dock by just hovering over them, instead of needing to click and activate them.

Comment: Actually, this was possible in Lion as well. My mother used it all the time for Entourage (she gets a lot of mail ;) )

Comment: I wish it made Adium stop flapping too :(

Answer (score 44):

### 'Do Not Disturb' Mode for Notification Center

In the Notification Center drawer, scroll up a bit past what appears to be the top. There's a switch 'Show Alerts and Banners' that is checked by default. Uncheck it to disable notifications for the rest of the day.

Alternatively, <kbd>option</kbd>-click on the Notification Center menu bar item to activate Do Not Disturb mode quickly.

[image]

Comment: The ⌥-click trick is particularly awesome. The Notification Center icon turns gray when in do-not-disturb mode! http://i.imgur.com/MV3Tt.png

Answer (score 39):

### Exposé for all windows

Mountain Lion re-introduces the pre-Lion feature to be able to disable **group by application** in Mission Control, this was enabled by default in Lion and could not be disabled.

You can disable this in:
 **System Preferences → Mission Control → Group windows by application**.

[image]

Comment: This alone may convince me to upgrade. I have avoided lion solely because of the removal of all-window expose.

Comment: This was already present in Lion... mine was even already ticked post-upgrade.

Comment: @Steve You are the very first person to say this. Please link a screenshot to verify your claim.

Comment: @gentmatt fortunately still have a Mac on Lion, will check when I get home!

Comment: @gentmatt realised my colleagues sat next to me haven't upgraded, looks like it was enabled by default and you couldn't turn it off, the ability to turn it off is what is new.

Comment: @Steve Yes, that's it. :)

Answer (score 38):

### Save As

...is back!

Try the following keyboard shortcut: <kbd>option</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. Or simply hit the <kbd>OPTION</kbd> key while the file menu is pulled down:

[image]

Comment: I love how they count this as a feature. They could have many more features if they removed them in previous versions and then added them back in in the later versions

Comment: @Jonathan They don't, we do (count it as a feature).

Comment: @Jonathan Looking at this list, it seems that *most* “new” features fall into this category: they’re just fixes of what Lion botched up. Not sure if I should be disappointed or delighted.

Comment: @jpc, it is listed on Apple's website, on the page which lists all the new features. Therefore they count it as a feature.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, it is called Mountain *Lion* though, so the changes arent going to be radical. I can't wait for OS 11

Comment: @Jonathan I’m fine with that. It just seems that Apple has finally conceded that Lion was a load of bullcrap to begin with. Fixing usability bugs should not require a paid upgrade.

Comment: If you assign a shortcut for duplicate in *System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts* The menu entry *Save As...* will be shown permanently - without the need to press ALT.

Comment: Also see http://www.tuaw.com/2012/07/29/get-save-as-back-on-mountain-lions-file-menu-easily-and-without/ for some more tricks around Save As

Comment: Warning: Save As may not do what you expect, if you're used to the old Save As. See the next-to-last paragraph of my article here: http://tidbits.com/article/13187

Answer (score 36):

Mountain Lion offers direct **video/audio encoding from Finder**.

Select one or more audio/video files, then right-click and choose “Encode selected video files”. You’ll get something like this:

[image]

Note: this doesn't work for already compressed audio files (like aac and mp3). This does work for CAFF, AIFF, AIFC, S2df, and WAVE as per the -2700 error message that shows up if you attempt this on an already compressed audio file.

Also, this may be found as a Sub-Menu Item of the *Services* menu (contextual or from the `File` menu) for those with a number of third party service actions enabled/installed.

Additionally, this does *not* preserve meta data like locations of movies or ID3 tags for AIFF files, etc!

Comment: I don't see this option when I right-click a mp4 file. Could it be a feature of Handbrake or some other application you have installed?

Comment: @jtbandes I did a fresh OS X 10.8 install this morning and have only installed XCode, some browsers, and some text editors since — no video software at all. I get this context menu on any `*.mp4` file: http://i.imgur.com/NFNj7.png

Comment: Oh I see — it's hiding under the Services submenu for me. Apparently it's an Automator action.

Comment: This was on Lion too, I'm pretty sure I've used it before yesterday.

Comment: Is there anyway it can preserve the meta information of the original movie? I'd like to compress the videos I've created with my iPhone but when I do this I lose the location information embedded in the original movie.

Answer (score 31):

## [Inline progress for downloads and file copies](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#finder)

Bars show progress.

[image] [image]

Comment: I wouldn’t say the sharing button is underdocument. :P It’s actually one of the main advertising points for OS X.

Comment: Unfortunately, the copy dialog box still appears.

Comment: This even works [in the Dock via Stacks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mHNus.png), in this case into the Downloads folder (that's the Download folder stack). Awesome. This is hands down the coolest feature in Mountain Lion for me.

Answer (score 29):

### Scrollbars get a bit wider when hovered over

Now it is easier to grab them.

[image: screenshot showing normal scrollbar, and new wider scrollbar]

Comment: This is awesome! Small, hidden, discrete while you scroll, bigger when you go to click… smart!

Comment: Yes please!! I hate trying to scroll with the Lion scrollbars.

Comment: Odd, this does not work when using *Show scroll bars: always*.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Tried both Finder and Safari.

Comment: @Arjan do the scrolls bar get bigger when you mouse over them? (whilst in "Show scroll bars: always" mode)

Comment: Looks like this only happens in "Show scroll bars: when scrolling" mode if you have a scroll wheel mouse.

Answer (score 27):

### Chess

...can now be played over the internet via Game Center.

[image]

Comment: Wow, why didn't they advertise this? Awesome feature.

Comment: Because it's Chess?

Comment: [Wait, how can I enable that?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57675/how-can-i-play-chess-over-game-center-in-mountain-lion)

Comment: @Moshe see my answer :)

Comment: This was advertised.

Comment: You'd think the graphics performance of Chess would have improved by now as well... I guess not ;)

Answer (score 27):

**Internet Sharing**

Internet Sharing now supports WPA2 encryption (and no longer supports WEP, apparently) when sharing a wired connection to Wi-Fi.

[image]

Comment: Glad to finally have WPA2 but removing WEP is disappointing. Some older devices only support WEP.

Comment: @KevinMark WEP is still (kind of) supported in Internet Sharing and AirPort Utility. If you option-click the drop-down menu in Security (in Internet Sharing), WEP 40-bit and WEP 128-bit appear as new options.

Answer (score 25):

Messages is AppleScriptable, including an Event Handler Suite! This could get fun.

[image]

Comment: Excuse-me, it's maybe a very dumb question, but where did upi find this `Messages.sdef` file, and what is this application you are using to reed it? Thank in advance!

Comment: Use AppleScript Editor and open the dictionary from the file menu

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's very powerfull as we can script actions for messages sends from any iOS device!

Answer (score 25):

## [Customizable sidebar](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#finder)

You can now drag/drop sections in the Finder side bar again.

[image: moving around the Favorites section of Finders side bar]

Comment: Du benutzt aber interessante Namen ;)

Comment: klar, immer doch

Comment: OH SWEET LORD! FINALLY!

Comment: This feature is documented by Apple.

Comment: How do you make the font size of the Finder side bar smaller?

Comment: System Preferences --> General --> Sidebar Icon Size

Comment: @GrahamPerrin Ah, you're right about that. I must have missed the criterion to only post un(der)documented things.

Comment: I later realised that the *under-documented* criterion didn't appear until revision 3 of the question. Apologies for any confusion.

Answer (score 25):

### Show scrollbars without scrolling

If you have a multi-touch input device (a multi-touch trackpad or Magic Trackpad), **resting two fingers on the device** will make the scrollbar appear as an indicator of your scroll position. You no longer have to scroll the document to see where you are.

[image]

<sup>Note: doesn't work with Magic Mouse.</sup>

Comment: I hate having to move my fingers on the trackpad to show the scrollbars in Lion. This is a much improved feature!

Comment: This seems to be Apple apps specific? Like I can see it in Finder and Safari, but no joy in Chrome.

Comment: @Arjan I suppose Chrome is not properly handling the event, since it looks like it's using standard scrollbars but you're right that it doesn't work.

Comment: Surely Chrome will soon get a new build that does it right.

Answer (score 24):

## [New date picker](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#calendar)

A small calendar appears in date entry fields. Example:

[image]

Comment: Lipiec!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 19):

## [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#system) and other screen savers

Mountain Lion includes a bunch of new kinetic photo-based screen savers.

You can select from several categories of stock images or choose a folder, iPhoto event, or Photostream as the source of images.

Go to System Preferences -> Desktop and Screen Saver -> Screen Saver and select one of the screen savers in the Slideshows category to try them out.

Personally, I'm a fan of Shifting Tiles.

[image]

Comment: Alas they have dropped my old favourite one.

Answer (score 19):

### Re-enable Web Sharing for individual users

May be more a "feature" than a feature, but anyway:

Per-user Web Sharing is gone from Preferences but can be easily re-enabled via Terminal.app. Copy the following snippet into `/etc/apache2/users/USER.conf`:

```
<Directory "/Users/USER/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and restart Apache with `sudo apachectl restart`.

Comment: Or, you can use that software, to activate/deactivate web sharing easily :) (from VirtualHostX editors) : http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/

Comment: I can't get this to work, Web Sharing stays on irregardless of the position of the switch in the preference pane?!

Comment: Maybe you can contact the developer ? I really don't know how I can help here lol. I know they're active on twitter for their main app (@virtualhostx), maybe they can help you there ? Sorry it doesn't work, it seemed pretty good..

Answer (score 18):

### Enhancements to Launchpad

There's now a [search bar](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#launchpad) on top, and when you mouse over the Launchpad icon while an app is downloading, you get progress information:

[image] [image]

Comment: It's good to know that you do not need to click the search field first - instead: **search by typing from anywhere** in Launchpad.

Comment: @gentmatt: the reason for the large screenshot was to see the dock icon too...

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I did not notice that :) But I did read about it in your text.

Comment: I'm confused. What does Launchpad have to do with an app being downloaded?!

Comment: @PooriaAzimi: well it lists all the apps. Whenever you install a new app in the App Store, the icon of that app "jumps" to the Launchpad, so it makes sense for launchpad to show the progress.

Comment: @PooriaAzimi: also note that a progress bar is now displayed under the "Applications" folder as well.

Comment: For opensourcers / Apple noobs: [Launchpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchpad_(Mac_OS_X)), not [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net).

Comment: Another enhancement to the Launchpad is the (possibility to) reduction of "clutter" apps. I noticed this with Diablo3 for example, where in Lion 2 apps where added "Diablo III" and "Diablo III Launcher", now it hides one of the two from the Launchpad.

Answer (score 18):

### The Mac App Store can be navigated with two-finger swipes

Back and forward are (finally) bound to the two-finger swipe gestures in the MAS just like they are in Safari.

Comment: I've been waiting for this. Awesome!

Comment: Still not the finder though.... :'(

Comment: @Jonathan You can go back and forward in Finder by holding option while making the mission control swipe (3 or 4 fingers). It probably doesn't allow two because some views have sideways scrolling.

Comment: If that isn't the weirdest combination.... How on earth did you find that. Some web pages also have horizontal scrolling but safari manages fine.

Comment: I worked on this last summer! You're welcome! :D

Comment: @jtbandes you worked on this last summer? At Apple?

Comment: Yes, it was one of the things I worked on (perhaps they are no longer using my code, but at least it was at one point) :)

Comment: And two major OS releases later, it can finally be full screened! @Moshe Hi! Sorry I missed you at WWDC!

Comment: @wjlafrance - hehe, I know. Maybe next time.

Answer (score 16):

### AirPlay Everywhere

AirPlay devices like Apple TV and Airport Express now show as system audio output devices, so any audio on your Mac can be streamed to them. There are two ways to do it.

#### The fiddly way

System Preferences > Sound > Output

#### The easy way

<kbd>option</kbd>-click on the volume control in the menu bar

Comment: Is this limited to newer Macs? I only tried with a software receiver, which works with iTunes and iOS as a sender, but the option for AirPlay as System Output won't show up. This is a Macbook Late 2008.

Comment: Not as far as I know. It works fine with my mid-2010 Macbook Pro.

Comment: Nevermind, I just made a dry run with my old Airport Express. Didn't actually try to get audio out, but it shows up in the drop down menu. I wonder what the performance is like, for a system output it better have a much shorter delay than it has when playing music or video through iTunes or QuickTime.

Answer (score 15):

## Three-finger tap for QuickLook

Tap **(but don't click)** with three fingers over an item in Finder to open QuickLook for that item. Tap again to close the QuickLook window. This is exactly like pressing the spacebar.

Answer (score 14):

## [Go full screen on any display](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#system)

It is now possible to use a fullscreen app on a screen other than the primary one.

To do so, drag your app on the screen of your choice and hit the fullscreen arrow or the fullscreen shortkey of the app.

Comment: What happens on the other screen?  My understanding was that the other screen was useless in Lion when you had an app full screened.

Comment: @Keen Unfortunately it is same as before in Lion, the other screen is useless.

Comment: that's a step in the right direction, though full screen mode is still utterly useless for me, since I work with two monitors.

Comment: that is a misleading use of "support".  "support" would mean that you could actually still USE more than monitor.. you know.. for more than one thing… you know.. like how it was for 20 years before Lion.  don't get me started on that "basically-Ballmered" feature!

Comment: This feature is documented by Apple.

Comment: [Multimon](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multimon/id522324709?mt=12) supports using the other display when an app is full screened.

Answer (score 14):

**Slightly better Dock appearance**

The Dock "shelf" (when the Dock appears at the screen bottom) is drawn in a less glassy way (looks more like brushed metal, less reflection, less wasted space).

Also, the active appication indicator lights are much more subtle that the glowing "orbs" that used to sit on the glass and look awful, and now look like little LEDs set into the edge of the shelf

[image]

Comment: This is useless for everyone (like me) who has their dock on the *side* of their screen. That dock's appearance has not changed.

Comment: Yes, @FakeName, but the side dock appearance is the good one. In fact, there's a way to make the bottom appearance look like the side appearance, and that's what I actually do. Makes the dock more compact, and the active application indicators are a lot clearer. So stay with your side dock and don't worry, be happy!

Comment: I wish they had made this same change in iOS!

Answer (score 13):

## Zoom in PDF with Quick Look

Easily zoom in to a PDF with Quick Look (without Preview).

Methods include:

- spread your fingers apart whilst the cursor is over the Quick Look window
- smart zoom, Magic Mouse double-tap with one finger.

It doesn't seem to work on anything but PDF documents.

Comment: Well, it's a step in the right direction. I've been lamenting the limitations of Quick Look for a while now. There's a step higher than skimming that this zoom enables, especially when the font used in the PDF is absurdly small.

Comment: Typical Apple doing something people want but not going all the way. This would be useful on images too...

Comment: @Jonathan. Well, they need something to save for the next release, now that they have a note and a reminder application. *rolls eyes*

Comment: I have normal vision, but find the difficulty I have reading plain text documents with QuickLook (and the inability to change those text rendering settings) to be a: needlessly inflexible  b: maddeningly frustrating  and c: an uncharacteristic F-you to anyone that doesn't have the vision of a 5-year old (aka, everyone, brailees, etc).

Answer (score 12):

**Dictation**

You can dictate text wherever you can type text - even in an application that has not been rewritten for Mountain Lion. You must go in System Setting -> Dictation & Speech to activate the feature.

Note that you must have an Internet connection, since this is Siri behind the scenes and your speech must be sent to Apple's servers for interpretation.

[image]

Comment: will this feature be available in spanish?

Comment: double press on function key (fn) to activate it & single press to finish. Its a handy shortcut for dictation.

Comment: Too bad that this cannot be done locally. An iPhone may not have the horse power, but a Mac should be able to....

Answer (score 12):

## New "Edit" toolbar in Preview.app

There is a new toolbar in Preview.app  to replace the old "Annotations" toolbar that brings all the basic editing features that Preview offers (including their awesome smart lasso and instant alpha) plus the addition of speech bubbles!
[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Accidental Dock icon removal prevention

When moving and icon outside of the dock, it doesn't delete automatically, you need to stay out for a little at a minimum distance before it deletes.

There is a [follow up question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57617/13414) asking how to disable this feature - preferebly using a `defaults write` command.

Comment: I removed the picture, because this picture does not help in understanding how the changed dock icon removal works.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explaining, was curious why you removed it

Comment: I was really confused after the ML install when I was trying to remove some default Apple stuff I don't need in the dock ;)

Answer (score 11):

Applications in the Get Info dialogue window are now expressly listed as 32-bit as opposed to just "Intel," which has been entirely dropped.

[image]

Comment: Let the "Apple's moving to AMD/ARM/back to PowerPC" conspiracies begin!

Answer (score 10):

**Week numbers in Calendar.app**

Calendar.app can now display week numbers.

[image: Week numbers in Calendar.app]

Comment: I always wondered who used week numbers. is it a thing that accounting people are into?

Comment: Good one :) About two-three times a year I have someone saying he/she can do some task "starting week X". Used to subscribe to some public calendar for those rare occasions.

Comment: I used it a ton working Meteorology.

Comment: It can be usefull for task repartition: "You do this even week, I do it odd week. We also can use it with statistic, eg: "how many money week 1, 2, 3, etc". The most important is to use the same mathod of counting, there are 3 or 4…

Answer (score 9):

### In-App File Manipulation

When you hover over the file name in the application bar you can *Rename, Move to iCloud, Move to.., Duplicate, Lock* and *Browse all Versions*.

Other than that, you can also have specific services that appear there.

[image]

Comment: In my view, this is the best new feature of Mountain Lion (especially in combination with the option to bring back the "Save Changes?" dialog when closing a document). The screen shot does not represent its full yummy goodness: you may also see a menu item letting you Revert to the state of the document when it was last opened or last saved (or both).

Comment: Provided a better screen shot

Comment: by the way, what do you use to make your screenshot? it's really great!

Comment: Probably Snapz Pro X.

Comment: @matt thanks, never heard of it but it look awesome. It's not cheap though...

Answer (score 9):

### User prompt for address book access

This has only been officially announced for iOS 6 but quietly made it's way into Mountain Lion.

Your address book data is located in:

```
/Users/my_name/Library/Application Support/AddressBook
```

So far, I've used a [firewall](http://www.metakine.com/products/handsoff/) to controll read/write access on a per-application basis, but Mountain Lion does this now itself:

[image]

Comment: In case you gave an app access to your contacts but change your mind later, just go to System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Contacts and uncheck the app.

Comment: This also happens for Location Services and Twitter account access. Which means it should do the same for Facebook access in a future OS update that enables the Facebook account type in the first place.

Comment: Are you wondering why some apps show your contacts even though you denied them access? See this question: **[Can OS X apps access my contacts even if I don't give them permission?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58561/13414)**.

Answer (score 8):

**Safari Tab Sharing:**

If you have more than 1 Mac signed into the same iCloud account, then you can access a list of any open Safari tabs on your other machines by clicking the button in the toolbar as follows:

[image]

So far so yeah yeah we all knew about this months ago, but:

---

Start: Previously undiscussed material

In addition to opening the tab it even captures certain state definitions, such as whether or not you have the page open in Reader mode or not (and opens the tab to match accordingly).  In reader mode on the remote tab?  You will be if you open it locally via iCloud tab sharing.

Also things like dynamic page titles are carried over such as the (1) that appears when a new question with activity is identified on this site for example  Have an open but unattended SE site tab open?  You'll be able to see how many new questions with activity just by watching the tab title change.  Same thing applies to Facebook chat windows etc, anything that alters the page title without you needing to navigate elsewhere in order for it to do so.

To open the shared tab in a new tab rather than replace the contents of the current one, simply <kbd>Command</kbd>+Click it

End: Previously undiscussed material

---

When iOS 6 is released, the same features will be available cross platform between Safari and Mobile Safari.

Comment: Ho ho ho, comedy downvoter :)

Answer (score 8):

**Better Dashboard Widgets Management**

The "widgets bar" at the bottom of Dashboard is gone. To manage what dashboard widgets appear, click the **+** button to enter a mode where you see all available widgets; click one to add it to your default set of widgets. A new search bar  helps you find the widget you want just like in the refined Launchpad. So, click...

## +

..at the **bottom left** to enter the "add widgets" mode:

[image]

Comment: Definitely a big fan of the improved Dashboard.

Answer (score 8):

Mountain Lion [removed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57445/4408) the option to show the estimated battery time remaining from the battery menu bar item.

This data can still be accessed if your battery is not fully charged and isn’t charging, though. In those cases, <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>ing the battery icon in the menu bar shows something like this:

[image]

Comment: Finally! That was such a deceptive feature lol

Comment: Oops ... I relied on this feature.

Comment: The option is still there but you must now ⌥-click on the battery status: this will show the estimated time at the top of the dropdown.

Comment: @WichertAkkerman Doesn’t work for me. All I see is this: http://i.imgur.com/jFGZ2.png

Comment: @MathiasBynens That's because your battery is already fully charged. Try discharing it a bit and then check again.

Comment: yeah, you should delete this item or re-word it. the feature is there and in fact uses more clarity in its wording -- if charging the text makes it clear that it's the duration until fully charged; if using the battery, it says "remaining."

Comment: @estephan500 Post edited.

Answer (score 7):

### Ask to keep changes when closing documents

You can now force Mountain Lion to ask whether you want to keep changes you made to a document when closing it, which effectively allows you to sidestep autosaving.

> System Preferences > General > [**√**] Ask to keep changes when saving
>   documents

Clearing the checkbox, as shown below, **allows** unsaved changes to be saved automatically.

[image]

Comment: Please try to avoid bloating answers. I think in this specific case the picture wasn't necessary.

Comment: I think having a nice screenshot for each one would be nice, in order to get TL;DR type people up to date in a quick skim through the page

Comment: Whoever downvoted this : you are wrong. The "Close windows when quitting an application" was there in Lion, but not this.

Comment: This is incorrect. That checkbox does _not_ disable automatic saving. It brings back the "Save changes?" dialog when you close the document, which is great; but in fact the document has already been autosaved behind the scenes.

Comment: @matt: I am aware of that, but for the user, this feels as though Autosave is disabled, imo. For me the most annoying part of Autosave is that when you made a bad change and then you closed the document it automatically kept your change even though I was used to being able to just say "Don't save" to effectively revert to the old version.

Comment: @houbysoft I totally agree, and I think this is a terrific change, but then _that's_ exactly what your tip should say. Don't say you can disable autosaving; you can't. Be accurate.

Comment: The screenshot shows **allowance** of automatic saving at close time. I edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin The answer is still inaccurate. I repeat, you _cannot_ avoid automatic saving. At close time, the document changes have _already_ been automatically saved. Regardless of the wording of the checkbox or the dialogs, what's happening is only that you are *alerted* to this fact so that you can revert if you like (using the Versions feature). That is something you could have done anyway. So the alert is *all* that is new. It's good, but you are not in fact avoiding / allowing automatic saving; it's happening, regardless.

Comment: @matt interesting, thanks for clarification. It's a community wiki so (I guess) please go ahead with whatever corrections you feel are necessary.

Comment: @GrahamPerrin I already did what I could - I downvoted the answer and have made several comments trying to correct this. My full explanation of what's new with Mountain Lion auto save is here: http://tidbits.com/article/13187

Comment: @matt I made some additional changes. You should be able to edit the answer yourself too. FWIW, I still think this is nit-picking. We all know that this doesn't completely disable autosaving, but it disables its most annoying aspect, and as a user you won't really tell the difference between this and no autosaving.

Comment: As the question evolved to focus on features that are under-documented, I think it's important to be accurate in the answers. After reading @matt's article, I find this answer in it current form potentially misleading …

Answer (score 6):

**Quickly Renaming Bookmarks in Safari**

When you click and hold on a bookmark on the Safari bookmark bar you can quickly rename it.

Answer (score 6):

**Documents in iCloud**

If an application is iCloud-savvy, its Open dialog has an iCloud tab. You can not only open documents here, but you can also drag documents into the cloud from the Finder, and you can create folders (drag one document onto another to do so).

[image]

Comment: This open dialog is very good, but the save dialog with iCloud is downright stupid.

Comment: Note that you can only access iCloud documents from the app that they were created/saved in. For example, Word won't be able to open a .txt file you created in TextEdit.

Answer (score 6):

**Document auto-locking removed!**

In Lion, an auto-saved document would automatically lock itself after two weeks of inactivity. (This time interval could be adjust thru a pref hidden deep in Time Machine.) In Mountain Lion, this "feature" has been quietly removed; no more auto-locking.

Comment: Could you please change the tone of this post to something less ranty?

Comment: Or just delete your answer and win the Peer Pressure badge like I just did :)

Comment: It's an important change that has not been advertised by Apple, so it answers the original question. And the tone is right too; this was a bad Lion feature and annoyed everyone, so it's good that in Mountain Lion they withdrew it.

Comment: @matt: Your second sentence is subjective--I for one used this feature quite often.

Answer (score 6):

### Quick access to Accessibility settings

Press <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to bring up a new Accessibility Options window that offers quick access to a subset of the settings from the Accessibility prefpane.

[image]

Comment: Nice find! I wish that Apple would also include an option to toggle dictionary or location services here.

Answer (score 5):

**Reading List caches content for offline use**

Reading List in Safari is not new (it was introduced in Lion). But in Mountain Lion, a Web page stored in the Reading List stores the *page*, not just the URL, so you can read the page later without having to download it from the network.

Comment: Should have been like that from the beginning. I mean, seriously: The Reading List in Lion was just a *hall of fame* for bookmarks.

Answer (score 5):

### When updating apps, Mac App Store reopens apps and offers to skip open apps

When Updating All in the Mac App Store, rather than going straight down the list and demanding you shut down each open app along the way, it offers to let you skip the apps that are running:

[image]

Even better, if you do let it close an app, it will automatically reopen it when the update is complete. Furthermore, once you have initiated the update, the apps that are going to be changed are locked and a helpful error message is presented from the App Store if you try to launch an app that is about to be (or in the middle of) being updated. All together, these make updating apps less prone to error or conflicts due to files being in active use during an update.

Answer (score 5):

## Multiple Time Machine Backup Destinations

In Time Machine you can now select multiple backup destinations.

---

[image]

---

That was from the "OS X Mountain Lion Core Technologies Overview".

You can select additional disks from System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the UI for this is somewhat broken. Most importantly, the menu bar no longer shows when the last backup was taken (it shows only the last backup and status for one of the drives).

Comment: Re: broken UI: 10.8.1 has improved this. Now it does show when the last backup was taken, even if it was to the "wrong" disk.

Comment: Re: improved in 10.8.1: Maybe not, after all.

Answer (score 5):

## Kernel Exclusively 64-Bit

> "Starting with Mountain Lion, OS X exclusively uses a 64-bit kernel, but it continues to run both 32-bit and 64-bit applications ([OS X Mountain Lion Core Technologies Overview](http://movies.apple.com/media/us/osx/2012/docs/OSX_MountainLion_Core_Technologies_Overview.pdf))"

Why this is a good thing:

> There are two reasons this is a good thing. The first is simple: 64-bit computing is necessary if you want one of the programs on your computer to have access to more than 4GB of RAM. Second, there are some speed boosts associated with running in 64-bit mode. The Intel processors that power Macs have built-in math routines that operate more efficiently in 64-bit mode, processing tasks in fewer steps. That means that certain math-intensive tasks will see a speed boost under Snow Leopard’s 64-bit applications ([Macworld](http://www.macworld.com/article/1142379/snow_leopard_64_bit.html)).

However, having a 64-bit kernel does have its downsides: some older 64-bit computers like the iMac (pre-Mid-2007), Macbook Pro (pre-Mid-2007), Mac Pro (pre-2008), and others are not able to run Mountain Lion. This has to do with the fact that now with Mountain Lion, Macs can only boot into 64-bit mode, but prior to that, Macs could boot into both 32 and 64-bit mode, so older Macs were able to boot into 64-bit mode, but their EFI firmware was 32-bit and therefore can only interface with a 32-bit kernel.

Comment: Note that almost all of the benefits were/are already available with the 32-bit kernel of OSX, and Lion already booted into a 64-bit kernel by default if supported by the hardware. (The hardware that didn't support it is the same hardware that Mountain Lion now fails to boot on)

Answer (score 4):

You can quickly get rid of a notification by hovering over it and swiping with 2 fingers from left to right (swipe it off the screen)

And if you just want to peek behind it or something you can click and drag it (one finger) to the left and when you let go it will bounce back.

Comment: If you drag it further to the left, it will stick in that position until you drag it back. Useful if you need to access a control behind the notification, but don't want to actually dismiss it.

Answer (score 4):

### Zoom and Mission Control/Launchpad play nice!

*Finally,* if you zoom in your screen (for example, by <kbd>⌃</kbd>+scrolling), activating Mission Control or Launchpad doesn't immobilize the viewport!

Answer (score 4):

## Improved Kernel Security (ASLR)

> "Apple introduced randomization of some library offsets in Mac OS X v10.5 (released October 2007). Their implementation does not provide complete protection against attacks which ASLR is designed to defeat.Mac OS X Lion 10.7 has improved ASLR implementation for all applications. Apple explains that "address space layout randomization (ASLR) has been improved for all applications. It is now available for 32-bit apps (as are heap memory protections), making 64-bit and 32-bit applications more resistant to attack." Since OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 the kernel as well as kexts and zones are randomly relocated during system boot" ([Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization#Mac_OS_X)).

This is beneficial in that it protects the user against the malware exploits that rely on fixed locations for some well-known system functions.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 3):

### Navigate forward/back while viewing a PDF in Safari

In Safari, if you are viewing a PDF, you can now use your normal 2-finger swipe to navigate forward or back! (Previously, this would only scroll the PDF or jump between pages if you used 3 fingers.)

Comment: The shortcuts for going back and forward no longer jump to previously viewed pages either.

Answer (score 2):

## Software Updates Now Come Through the App Store

Whenever you get software updates, they now come through the App Store. You can check for updates like this (which opens the App Store):

[image]

Prior to Mountain Lion, software updates took place in a separate application that looked like this:

[image]

Comment: If my iLife apps are not from app store, what happens?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - You mean if they're from a disk?

Comment: Yes, or if I haven't updated my iLife '08 from Snow Leopard.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - Then the new version of Software Updates should work for you.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo My fresh install of iLife '09 was updated via the App Store as well - even though I installed it using a CD i bought.

Comment: This happens with most all Apple software the same way - I have Aperture 3 from disk, and it updates fine through the Mac App Store, as well as iLife from disks.

Answer (score 2):

### Click-and-hold to toggle Notification Center

Click-and-hold the Notification Center icon to show your notifications; once you release the mouse button, they'll hide. This also works if you've assigned a keyboard shortcut for Notification Center (press-and-hold the key, then release).

Answer (score 2):

### Browse through photos in screensavers via keyboard

In any of the various photo screensavers, you can hit the left or right arrow keys to manually navigate between photos.

Answer (score 1):

### Clipboard content is persistent through reboots

The clipboard is not cleared on shutdown. All data in the clipboard remains there even after a power cycle.

Answer (score 1):

### Take app screenshots without shadow

You can now take screenshots of apps without the shadow. Press ⇧⌘4 to enter screenshot mode, then press space to select a window, like normal. However, instead of simply clicking to take the screenshot, **⌥-click the window to take the screenshot without the shadow**.

[image]
[image]

<sup>On the left is the default style of screenshot; on the right is the sans-shadow screenshot.</sup>

Comment: upvoted - thanks for doing the work to find this great answer a proper home.

Answer (score 0):

**Navigate through a PDF in Mail.app by scrolling the mouse while hovering over it**

The need to open a PDF in Preview/Quickview just in order to see pages other than the first one, is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

When **Show contact photos in the message list** is enabled, user image additions/edits from Contacts.app are updated **immediately** in Mail.app (not after relaunch, as in Lion)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Mission Control, holding <kbd>option</kbd> will immediately show the `+` icon for adding a new desktop and `X` icons on each secondary desktop. You can then click these icons immediately, instead of hovering and waiting for them to appear after a delay.

Comment: Can you definitely confirm that this is new in Mountain Lion? I'm confident that this existed already in OSX 10.7 Lion.

Comment: I hadn't discovered this until Mountain Lion, but it's possible it was there in Lion and I never noticed it. I don't have a Lion installation anymore to test on. Still, even if it's not new, it remains an "undocumented" feature of Mountain Lion... ;)