# How to regain features from Safari 5 that are not found in Safari 6?

Tags: safari, web-browser, bonjour

I upgraded to Mountain Lion, there are a **lot** of differences in Safari 6.

Have the four features below been relocated?

If not relocated, are there fixes?

- Activity window (previously: Window -> Activity) is gone.
- Bonjour access from the bookmarks menu is gone.
- Ability to empty cache (previously: Safari -> Empty Cache) is gone.
- <kbd>delete</kbd>/<kbd>backspace</kbd> key no longer works for going to the previous page.

Comment: Also missing is the RSS reader. That's one reason I'm not updating to Safari 6 for now.

Comment: [How to mimic Safari 5 Activity window with Mountain Lion, to save FLV video files?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/59449/8546)

Comment: In Safari 5, I use the Activity window to see all my tabs of all my windows. Is there a way to do that in Safari 7 ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco - Can you take a screenshot of you doing that so I can get a better idea of what you mean?

Comment: @qegal — [Here is a screen photo — not taken by me.](https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/static/images/2012/07/5activity-window.png) There are all the tabs of all the windows. So I can type the first letters of the title, and the line gets selected. I remember that I can also search with Apple F. When I have the line selected, I press Return, and shazam ! Safari gives me the wanted window, with the wanted tab selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action for emptying caches was moved to the develop menu:

[image]

You can still see resources in the web inspector:

[image]

To download YouTube videos, reload the page after opening the web inspector and double-click the `videoplayback` resource. To download it, you have to focus the location bar and press ⌥↩. ⌘S only saves some metadata.

Comment: It looks like the page resources isn't as comprehensive as it used to be.  I'm seeing only a subset of what I used to see in the Activity window.  Embedded videos, for example.  I used to be able to open the Activity window and option-click (or control-click, I don't quite remember) to download the actual file.  But now I'm not seeing them at all.

Comment: @David It could depend on the way the videos are served. I can't see the files for videos on YouTube, but ones on other sites are shown in both the resource and network request views.

Comment: Ah, it does appear in the network request view.  However, I'm not sure how to save from that view.  Is there some key-click combination?  I've clicked the little arrow and it looks like it's loading the video (could be a while in this case), will it be savable after that?

Comment: Never mind, I'm able to copy the URL from elsewhere in that display (on the right where the requested resource's details are displayed), paste it into a new tab, and option-return to initiate a download.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, Bonjour is still there, but you have to include it yourself. Just go to Preferences > Bookmarks, and enable what you'd like there.

Answer (score 7):

The <kbd>delete</kbd>/<kbd>backspace</kbd> key navigation has been removed.

To restore it:

1. Quit Safari.
2. Open Terminal
   and enter this code at the command line:

   defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2BackspaceKeyNavigationEnabled -bool YES
3. Restart Safari.

Answer (score 2):

## Bring any tab to foreground

I used the **Activity window of Safari 5.x** to switch between tabs. Effective for all tabs of all windows, including windows that were minimised before quit. Very **quick and simple**:

- double-click.

### Without the Activity window

#### [Sessions](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8247646/sessions/index.html) 1.3.0.2

The popover works as expected – click and hold the toolbar item to reveal a menu.

The manager, which appears in a separate tab, fails to list reopened windows that were minimised before quit. I reported this bug to the developer, with reference to this post.

Answer (score 1):

> Bonjour access from the bookmarks menu is gone.

Well I found out that in Mountain Lion, Bonjour is available from Safari > Bookmarks > Bonjour > Device.

I still haven't figured out the other problems.

Comment: I don't see a Bonjour entry in the Bookmarks menu?!