# How to make the Backspace key to take me to the previous page in Safari 6?

Tags: safari, keyboard, macos

<kbd>Backspace</kbd>/<kbd>Delete ⌫</kbd> no longer works as a back button in Safari 6.

How to make the Backspace key to take me to the previous page in Safari 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually asked a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58812/mountain-lion-safari-changes) (but more broad so this isn't a duplicate). I got this as an answer (it works, I tested it):

Write the below line in terminal:

> defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2BackspaceKeyNavigationEnabled -bool YES

Then restart Safari.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Apple removed the backspace (probably to prevent users that wanted to edit a form field to accidentally go to the previous page)

You've got a number of options:

- Use the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd><-</kbd> shortcut for back.
- Use the 2 finger swipe gesture (push the webpage to the right)
- Install the [BringBackDelete](https://github.com/heardrwt/BringBackDelete) safari extension.

Answer (score 0):

Type this into your Terminal.app:

`defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Back" "⌫"`

Comment: That would also disable the default shortcut (⌘[).

Comment: But it would at least enable backspace, which is what OP wants.

Comment: The hidden preference would also restore ⇧⌫ for forward.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to leave this here for when someone stumbles on this topic through a Google search (as I did) with the opposite problem and wants to DISABLE the backspace key (that was added back again in later versions of Safari).
I managed to fix it using the following key in the Safari prefs list to map it to something that doesn't reload a page. I used "Export as PDF…" since I never use that, and certainly with a keyboard shortcut, but you can use any menu item that you never use.

defaults write com.apple.Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Export as PDF…" "⌫"