# How do I download embedded media such as Flash video in Safari 6?

Tags: safari, data-transfer, adobe-flash, safari-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mimic Safari 5 Activity window with Mountain Lion, to save FLV video files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59449/how-to-mimic-safari-5-activity-window-with-mountain-lion-to-save-flv-video-file)

It used to be in Safari 5 and such I could open the Activity Viewer with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, but no longer in Safari 6. How then do I download embedded files such as Flash Video from a website for offline viewing in Safari 6? Is there a Safari Extension (my Google-fu hasn't turned up anything useful on that front)?

Comment: You can open resource for the video (or `videoplayback` in YouTube) from the web inspector. To download it, press ⌥↩ on the location bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out last night. Due to a weird flaw in the Inspector, I didn't notice this before.

If you intend to download anything loaded via a plugin you must have the inspector open *before* you have the plugin load the resource. This is easiest when the site does not autoload/play a video or music file. [ClickToPlugin](http://hoyois.github.com/safariextensions/clicktoplugin/) is particularly helpful in this regard.

1. Enable the debug menu if you haven't. (Preferences > Advanced)
2. Go to the web page of the resource you want. (e.g. http://www.example.com/kittenvideo.html)
3. Pull up the inspector. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> now pulls up the Inspector.
4. Now load the resource you want to download.
5. Back to the inspector, look at the list of files. Look for audio, video, etc under the Other folder.
6. Select the resource you want, then look to the right of the window under location and copy the full URL.
7. Open the Download window (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>)
8. Paste the URL in the Downloads window to download.

So now there are just a few extra steps, but the paste to the downloads still works as before.