# Safari Downloader+ and Streaming Media

Tags: jailbreak, software

Using Safari Downloader+ on iOS 8.

- How can I prompt download for streamable media?

Direct links to files work without any problems whatsoever, but streamable media doesn't prompt anything more than streaming (in what seems to be Apples QuickTime player).

Answer (score 1):

Stream media have the download disabled.

You would need a special Safari add on to record/download them.

For more resources see following:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/69883/46541

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/72914/46541

Comment: How about a link extractor for the specific media? Does that exist?

Comment: Yes it does, I have one. But it is a add on to my Firefox browser. Anything that plays on my screen can be also downloaded for later viewing. You would have to look for something like that for Safari. Or you could use the QuickTime player screen recording with Sunflower audio diverter (bit more complicated).

Comment: Well my question is about iPhone usage, actually.

Comment: I know, so did you Google for it ?