# Safari 6 in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to regain features from Safari 5 that are not found in Safari 6?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58812/how-to-regain-features-from-safari-5-that-are-not-found-in-safari-6)

My question is about the removal of the Activity Window in Safari 6.
Is there anyway to accomplish the same results in Safari 6?
Is Apple working on a fix for this?

I'm using Mountain Lion