# How can I play chess over Game Center in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, game-center

I've looked in Game Center on Mountain Lion and in the Chess game, but I can't seem to see a way to play Chess over Game Center. Does Chess for Mountain Lion  support turn-based play? If it does, how can I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have added your systems knows about your Apple ID (go to *System Preferences -> Users & Groups -> Your User -> Apple ID*).

Then launch Chess; obviously you'll need to have an internet connection.

After a short wait (a second or two in my case, might depend on your internet connection), a badge like the following should appear in the Chess window:

[image]

After it appears, you should simply be able to go to *Game -> New...* and select *GameCenter Match* in *Players*.