# Game Center in Mountain Lion won't let me log in

Tags: macos, game-center

I'm trying to log in to Game Center using my Apple ID but it just won't let me do it. Actually, nothing happens: no error messages, just *nothing*.

I think there is an issue, because I also get a pop-up window where I suppose a new registration could be done within the same program, but it's blank (*Annulla* means *Cancel*):

[image: Screenshot]

Apart from what is being suggested in [this question about Chess over Game Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57675/13115), why isn't the simple log in working? I could use the workaround but I want the *standard way* to work anyways.

Comment: Try setting your computer to English, perhaps?

Comment: @jtbandes What does it have to do with this? I can't log in, why should computer language have something to do with this?

Comment: It's possible that there is some error in the localization that causes layout problems with the login dialog...

Comment: I experienced this bug on English as well.  It's the Terms and Conditions for Game Center which do not load properly for some reason.  If you have previously activated your Apple ID as a Game Center account on an iOS device, you will not experience this.  Using an iOS device to agree to the terms is one workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. For me, there was a verification screen that popped up behind the login screen. I could not see it at all! Not sure why I thought of it, but dragging the frontmost window out of the way showed me the verification screen, I did what needed to be done there, and on I went to Game Center to be underwhelmed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug that causes this. I can't log in either, and the issue isn't with the account because creating a new profile didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you ever got this resolved, but I just had pretty much the same problem in Mavericks. The only difference is that, rather than being stuck on that blank screen, the screen would show up, disappear, ask me to log in again, and repeat in a never ending loop. *What I did to solve this* was quit out of Chess, but leave Game Center open. This then let me log in normally and it worked fine after that.