# Apache 2 `UserDir` problem in OS X Mountain Lion (10.8) Server after upgrade from Lion (10.7)

Tags: macos, upgrade, osx-server, user-account, apache

I had a Mac under OS X Lion. I upgrade it to Mountain Lion, and buy the [*OS X Server* software in the *AppStore*](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/os-x-server/id537441259?mt=12).

Since the beginning, I use the Apache version bundled in Mac OS, and it work fine.

But after solving some problems (like the change of location of the main directory from `/Library/WebServer/Documents` to `/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default`), I can't figure out how to configure `UserDir` to work again!

As explained [here](http://old.nabble.com/Mountain-Lion-%28not-server%29,-Apache2,-and-MacPorts-p34221471.html):

> Please note - the Mountain Lion install removes the contents of the directory
>   `/private/etc/apache2/users`
>   so if you counted on those configuration files working for you, oops.

So, I follow advices found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19115015#19115015), and finally my file `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` look like this:

```
#
# UserDir: The name of the directory that is appended onto a user's home
# directory if a ~user request is received.  Note that you must also set
# the default access control for these directories, as in the example below.
#
UserDir Sites

#
# Users might not be in /Users/*/Sites, so use user-specific config files.
#
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
<IfModule bonjour_module>
       RegisterUserSite customized-users
</IfModule>

<Directory "/Users/*/Sites/">
Options Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But, event after some `sudo apachectl restart` or reboot, impossible to acces again to my `UserDir` `/Users/utilisateur/Sites/` through `http://127.0.0.1/~utilisateur`

Can you provide me some advice for the configuration please?
Remember: I've installed the Server software from the AppStore.

Thank you in advance!

[EDIT] I also tried these recommendations: [Mountain Lion, Apache, Sites folder, htaccess and mod_rewrite](http://nirusu.me/articles/apache), but it dosen't help…

**[EDIT 2] In response to the possible duplicate with ["How do I get my user directory working for web sharing again?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/58078/10428), I will say that in my case, it's not a `permission denied`, but a `404 Not Found`. It is probably due to the concomitant installation of the [*OS X Server* application from the *AppStore*](http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/os-x-server/id537441259?mt=12), so, it's a distinct issue IMHO…

In fact, I've tested the solution provided, and it does not work at all for me.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get my user directory working for web sharing again?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58078/how-do-i-get-my-user-directory-working-for-web-sharing-again)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the Apache configuration files in `/etc/apache2` are not at all considered by the Apache version provided by the *Server* application.

With the Server application, all configurations are in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2`

As the `ReadMe.txt` of this directory says, the default apache configuration file is `httpd_server_app.conf`, and I just had to uncomment the line `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` in this file!

problem solved.

[EDIT]
As notified by **Kristopher Johnson**, it may also be necessary to uncomment `LoadModule apple_userdir_module`

Comment: I found that I also had to uncomment the line that starts with `LoadModule apple_userdir_module ...`

Answer (score -2):

the answer is as follow:

you must to check if you have a file with the name .conf in this directory:

```
/private/etc/apache2/users/
```

by default I think you have the Guess.conf file with this content:

```
# cat /private/etc/apache2/users/Guest.conf 
<Directory "/Users/Guest/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you have the user "macuser" and you want to use `localhost/~macuser` URL, then you must create the `macuser.conf` with the correct information (Sites directory, probably `/Users/macuser/Sites`). After the change you need to restart the apache process:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: The question is already answered, and this answer do not solve the problem at all because the Server App had moved the configuration files (as you can read in my solution). So, you replied without completely reading the question neither the answer...