# Can OS X apps access my contacts even if I don't give them permission?

Tags: macos, contacts, skype

After I upgraded to Mountain Lion, I noticed that apps have started asking for permission to access my contacts.  Very cool.

When Skype initially asked for permission to access my contacts, I decided not to grant it.

However, when I loaded Skype this morning, I noticed that my Skype contacts screen was still getting populated from my Address Book.

I double-checked in the Security prefpane, and Skype still does *not* have permission to access my contacts.

How is Skype getting my contacts?  Can apps access my Address Book even if I have explicitly denied them permission?

Comment: I'm not sure how Skype works, but perhaps Sykpe already imported the contacts into itself before, so it has them already? If you add a new contact into your Address Book does it appear in Skype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this was an upgrade install, you had used Skype already for quite a while, right? I assume that Skype is simply displaying **its own database** which it build-up before Mountain Lion.

I myself don't use Skype, so I just installed it and used my firewall to monitor what files Skype accesses:

[image]

During the setup I was also prompted by Mountain Lion if I wanted to grant access to my contacts. I denied access. If I had granted access to my Contacts, the firewall would have intercepted as a second barrier (I've set it up this way). But this was not necessary.

After several restarts Skype had written to `~/Library/Address Book Plug-Ins/`, but your contacts are stored in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook`. As you see in the first picture, Skype never gained access to my contacts.

And indeed, there are no entries in Skype's own address book:

[image]

So what you have probably achieved now in Mountain Lion is that Skype will not gain access to any **new Contacts** that you add to your address book. When Skype had access to your contacts in Lion, it copied them already and there's nothing you can do to undo that.

Comment: Makes sense. That's what I was going to say too.

Comment: "and there's nothing you can do to undo that", well, you could just remove them from Skype.

Comment: @vcsjones I bet Skype has copied them to its servers. Just like many other social apps. *That* is the actual problem :(

Comment: Confirmed.  I deleted the contents of `~/Library/Application Support/Skype`, and my Address Book contacts no longer appear in Skype.