# How do I use say command creatively to prank my coworkers/friends?

Tags: macos, screen, script

I'm designing a creative / funny prank for OSX via command line. By running in the background, most users would not notice it when she/he first starts using the computer.

Using `say` command with creepy voice (`Deranged`) is my best bet. Setting volume to very low during saying the sentences is even more creepy! My problem is, I don't know how to grab current current volume to set it to the same volume after `say`ing.

```
sascript -e "set Volume 2"
say "Naaame I see you" -v Deranged -r 20
sascript -r "set Volume 0"
sleep 600
sh thisscript.sh
```

Can I get the current volume and store it in a variable using unix shell scripts?

Comment: I'm not so sure this is a good post. This is more of an open-ended subjective post. If you'd like to edit it and make it more objective, that'd be great, but I'm going to vote to close it for now.

Comment: **I think this question is off topic.**  BUT, I can't resist sharing this: Try fixing a piece of tape to the bottom of the user's mouse. Infared or laser won't pick up the location, so looks like their screen froze.

Comment: I intent to be ask a open ended question. Just like [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: @Mohsen: personally, I think the question you cite is an exception to the usual AD format. Although it’s open-ended, it’s clear what the value and merit of the question is. I don’t think the same can be said for this one; pranks aren’t especially useful or helpful.

Comment: As mentioned, this is a list/poll style question that is not as productive or educational as the ones that we have allowed in the past.

Comment: I would close it if it's not inline with sites values. But pranks are sometimes valuable to users.

Comment: @Mohsen I love that avatar. Hit us up in [chat] and we might see about a blog post on pranks. I bet we could use the chat rooms to make some discovery and put it on the blog. I'd even help promote the chat room since it's summer and a little fun can't hurt if it's in the right place. Heck, the site owners often do hat contests and such so we could try a new way to have fun, no?

Answer (score 2):

You could always get the volume, change the volume, say your line, and then restore the volume within the AppleScript:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set currentVolume to output volume of (get volume settings)
set volume output volume 1
say "Hello" using "Deranged"
set volume output volume currentVolume
```