# How Can I Log Crontab File Writes

Tags: monitoring, cron

I'm looking for a way to log crontab file writes. A friend of mine pranked me, and did something that occasionally adds `` */5 * * * * say "deranged" "The current time is `date`" ``

I haven't been able to identify a pattern yet: Nothing for 2 weeks, then twice in 5 minutes. I'm trying to find the process that writes to the crontab. Is there any way to log crontab writes to a file so I can catch this thing?

Comment: Is your [friend named Moshen](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95171/how-do-i-use-say-command-creatively-to-prank-my-coworkers-friends)?

Comment: Nope :). It's not on system restart or any common terminal arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run this:

```
sudo fs_usage | grep cron
```

I'd run it using tmux or screen so that you can detach and check later. Depending on how many cron jobs you have, this could generate a lot of messages and you'll want to not run it where a runaway process could cause harm. (backup, check filesystems for space, etc...)

You can also use `mdfind` to see if you can locate the file/script/package that is calling crontab (perhaps) and correlate that with the times when the actual filesystem changes are happening.

```
mdfind crontab
```

Comment: No luck with mdfind. It's happening more frequently now, so fs_usage will likely return something soon.