# Disable volume adjustment sound effect while audio is playing

Tags: audio, sound-volume

When there is currently no audio playing, the 'blip blip' sound effect is useful to know where the volume is currently set.  But when there IS audio playing, you don't need the sound effect, yet is plays anyway.  It is annoying, especially if you are using your computer for a presentation, or music at a party, etc.

Has anyone found a way to disable the volume adjustment sound effect for when audio is already playing?

Comment: I'd really like a solution that causes *precisely* the behaviour described by [@Jason Hartley](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/40563/jason-hartley), though; if someone could write a tiny daemon that automatically swaps this behaviour (presumably, the System Preferences setting is `defaults`-writeable, somewhere?) based on whether there's currently audio playing to any device … or even a binary patch to Apple services … I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when clicking the <kbd>Volume Up/Down</kbd> keys to disable the volume adjustment notification sound.

Comment: omg.  That's it?  It's been there all along???  lol.

Comment: Yup, as are many other hidden tips/tricks: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 3):

Under **System Preferences / Sound / Sound Effects** unmark *Play feedback when volume is changed*.

Comment: Should? You might better be certain when you add answers.

Comment: @Rob Your comment really helps.

Comment: User78453, I was hoping that there was a way to disable the sound effect for when audio is already playing, but keep it enabled for when there is no audio playing.