# Hidden gems or tricks in OS X Yosemite (10.10)

Tags: macos

In addition to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-os-x-features-or-tips-and-tricks) question I'd like to start a new question specifically for the new OS X Yosemite.

As I'm always curious about the announced items, there are many times hidden gems or nice tricks in new OS X versions.

Please share your hidden tricks (*one per answer*)! Please do not add "default" tricks which are available in all previous versions.

Comment: Yes, what's different between this one and the older question?

Comment: @Rnhmjoj This one is less broad than the other one, as this is only Yosemite. So I don't know - just waiting for it to be reopened.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I think I haven't been clear. I think there is no reason why this should be on hold while the other is ok.

Comment: @mbc I mean I don't understand why it is "too broad". I think this kind of question are really useful.

Comment: @Rnhmjoj We agree, I’ve misunderstood you then.

Answer (score 4):

Using **currency calculator directly in Spotlight** by typing in a number and a currency. Spotlight is automatically showing the most used conversions.

[image]

Comment: This also works for the conversion of units like meters, yards, kg and pounds.

Comment: If the currency you're interested in is not listed you can for example type "4 eur in aud" to get Australian Dollars.

Answer (score 4):

**Sign a PDF document with your Trackpad.**

When you open up a PDF, you can click on the new *Markup Icon*, and then choose *"Sign"*. You can choose between a file or create a new Signature. After you chose *"New Signature*", **you can use your Trackpad to write your Signature**.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### Dark mode

[image]

Open **system preferences**, go to **generals** and tick **use dark menu bar and dock**
[image]

Now the dock, menu bar, spotlight and other UI elements are dark.

It's not a secret feature but not so easy to turn on.

Answer (score 1):

**Editing images directly in Mail**

You don't have to edit images in Preview any more before you send them over to another person.

1. Hover over the image which you included inside your E-Mail
2. Klick on the arrow on the top right corner
3. Click **Markup**

After that, you can use the same tools as in Preview:

[image]