# How to customize drag-n-drop-to-Terminal path escaping results?

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, ui, cocoa

How can I change the way in which filenames are escaped (formatted) when dragged from applications and dropped into Terminal?

For example, paths may be escaped with `\`, just spaces (), or other options.  `Path Finder`, for example, has the following options under `Copy Path`:

- UNIX
- HFS
- Windows
- Terminal
- URL
- Name

Specifically, I'm looking for the setting(s) that can be applied via the shell, such as:

```
defaults write tld.domain.appOrLib SomeSettingScope -string "SettingDetails"
```

Comment: XtraFinder has the same options as you listed, and it's free and will integrate directly with Finder.

Comment: I'm looking for the general functionality that will work across all apps so that, for example, I can drag a document from TextMate's titlebar and have the escaping a certain way upon drop into Terminal.

Comment: @ylluminate I don't really understand this question - but  i'd like to try to. You need a Terminal/bash setting/switch which either formats a dragged path_to_file UNIX like (/path/to/file), Windows-like (\path\to\file) or HFS like (path:to:file) etc.?

Comment: So @klanomath, you understand that when you drag something from Finder or a titlebar, into terminal then the file and its accompanying path are escaped traditionally with backslashes, right? This behavior can be changed to give no escaping or apparently other escape sequences as well. I would like to understand how these options are set in OS X, which I assume can be issued as a shell command as noted above.

Comment: @ylluminate I don't think so. I believe the Terminal app interprets the file path and escapes if if necessary. If you can provide a link to where it says the behavior can be changed, then I'd be happy to help you figure it out.

Comment: @IronCraftMan this is interesting. In order to test out the idea, I fired up iTerm and found that it does indeed perform escaping as per the terminal app itself. For example, in my Terminal, something happened and it no longer escapes dropped in items; it simply gives an unquoted path, but in iTerm, it still escapes the path with the backslash method.  I'm not seeing how or why it would have changed behavior for me in Terminal, but seeing this with iTerm clearly indicates that it must be a function of the app vs the inbound drop lib...