# Open files in Tabs in Numbers

Tags: numbers, tabs

When I choose **File > New** or **File > Open** from Numbers menu, the file opens in a new window. How can such a file be opened in a new tab rather than in a new window? It would also be great to have the option to have all the files in the last session opened automatically (all previous tabs) as it happens, for example, in Safari.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable Tabs you need to set the "Open in Tabs" option in **System Preferences** -> **Dock** to "Always".

Comment: You should put this in "[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-macos-features-or-tips-and-tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400/please-share-your-hidden-macos-features-or-tips-and-tricks)" if it is not already there.