# How can I re-connect to a previously-connected Bluetooth Devices without going through System Preferences?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, shortcut, airpods, ventura

I frequently want to switch AirPods connection from my phone to my MacBook laptop. I am not signed into iCloud on my laptop, but have my AirPods connected.

I know one way to do this, which is to open System Preferences, find the Bluetooth settings, then hover over the device under "My Devices" and click connect
[image: bluetooth menu in system preferences]

This is way too slow though, too many clicks for such a simple task. The next quickest way I can think of is to search for bluetooth in spotlight search, but annoyingly, starting to type "bluetooth" autocompletes to "Bluetooth File Exchange" instead of "Bluetooth". So that isn't quick/convenient either (and I still have to click around in the system preferences).

[image: spotlight search results]

Is there any better way to do this? Why is there not something in the toolbar next to the wifi symbol to allow me to connect to my bluetooth device to listen to my music? Feels like I'm missing something...

Comment: Here is a good resource to peruse:  [hidden macOS features or tips and tricks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/400/119271).  The answer to your Bluetooth query is on the first page a little ways down.  It's an excellent resource!

Comment: @Allan amazing resource, thanks Allan, very handy. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings->Control Center and find the  Bluetooth under the Control Center Modules. Then, make sure "Show in Menu Bar" option is selected within the drop-down menu next to it.

This option places a Bluetooth icon somewhere to the right of your Mac's Menu Bar. You can see any of the previously connected devices to your Mac after clicking on the Bluetooth icon in the Menu Bar and connect to or disconnect from any one of them without going through System Settings.

Answer (score 2):

I click on the Bluetooth symbol in the menu bar (top right) and get a list of the recent devices that have connected.

[image]