# Is there a way to make my MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard hibernate with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, keyboard, sleep-wake, hibernate

Is there a way to hibernate at all?
I know if the battery dies when it's sleeping it hibernates, but is there a way to go directly to hibernate with a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377/can-macs-be-put-in-hibernation-voluntarily

Comment: @calavera It's definitely related, though the answer to that question was not a keyboard shortcut, so I'm inclined to keep this question open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option-Command-Eject is the system-standard key to put the machine to sleep.

If you want to do more than sleep, you can use this preference pane to fine-tune the sleep or hibernate behavior: http://www.jinx.de/SmartSleep.html

Edit:

More information about sleep, hibernate, and more on the Mac: http://www.geekguides.co.uk/104/how-to-enable-hibernate-mode-on-a-mac/