# Is there a way to hibernate in mac?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make my MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard hibernate with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/is-there-a-way-to-make-my-macbook-pro-running-snow-leopard-hibernate-with-a-keybo)

I am using mac os x snow leopard. Is there a way to hibernate?
also any keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Note: apart from hibernating an extensive period of time, booting up from a hibernation will take more power/battery than waking from sleep.

Comment: @Gerry: not really: only if the memory was lost. A Mac always persists the memory to disk (hibernation). When booting it checks if the memory is still there (fast) and only if needed reads back from disk (slow)

Comment: Memory is lost when hibernating as RAM loses power. And the act of reading it out again from disk will typically consume more power than several hours of standby. I'm just talking hypothetically if you can force a Mac to hibernate (as we know the concept in Windows) instead of standby. I don't know if you can.

Comment: @Gerry: there is not something like 'Windows hibernate'. As stated in my answer a Mac always hibernates and sleeps and the same time (every time it goes to sleep it first writes memory on disk). When you wake up it only has to read from disk if Mac was powerless. You don't have to decide in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Mac model and OS X version, you might check out [Deep Sleep](http://deepsleep.free.fr/), a dashboard widget that gives you more control over the sleep/hibernate behavior. This [Macworld article](http://www.macworld.com/article/53471/2006/10/sleepmode.html) goes into more detail about what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X (from 10.4) after going to sleep will write the memory content to disk ([safe sleep](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/10328.html)). After the blinking white led stops the "hibernate operation" will be completed.

If power is still available your Mac will wake up instantaneously from memory. If power (and the memory content) was lost your Mac will take a little time more to wake up (from hibernation) since the memory content has to be read from disk.