# Macbook Air shutting off on lid close

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, system-settings, power-management, power-nap

Every time I close the lid of my Macbook Air, it turns off and I have to manually start it later when I open the lid again.

It also doesn't persist some of my settings such as volume level, desktop layouts (order of screens and which applications are full screened), and command line PATH changes such nvm's currently used node version.

Kind of a "you don't know what you don't know" situation. I'm not sure what to terms to use to search for this kind of behavior.

**Edit:** Adding some extra information as requested. I am on the following:

- 13-inch Macbook Air from Early 2014
- Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.6)

In System Preferences > Energy Saver > Battery, I have "Put hard disks to sleep when possible" checked and "Enable Power Nap while on battery power" unchecked.

I've looked through other potentially relevant areas of System Preferences and haven't found anything that works. I've done some Googling, but haven't found anything that is related and I'm unsure of what other terms I could use to search.

**Edit 2:** The issue seems to have been resolved. There's nothing in particular that I tried that worked, but it's resolved now. Thanks for reading and responding!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the model of device, OS, etc. Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review -

Comment: Thanks @fbara! I've edited my question to add a bit of clarification. Do you have any other suggestions on how I could improve my question?

Comment: Check utilities > console and maybe give us the last few lines before the shutdown so we can figure out the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I recently swapped my 17" Macbook for a 13" Retina. Every time my 17" would run out of battery (while in sleep mode), my computer would go into hibernation. Recently, it has been shutting down completely.

After doing some digging, I found out that because I use an [app](http://appgineers.de/mountain/) to prevent my SD card from being ejected (I'm using it as additional storage), it's causing issues with the deep sleep option of macOS.

If the issue comes back, take a look at these links that may offer insights into this.

**More on macOS hibernation:**
[Do MacBooks have a true "Hibernate" option?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51725/do-macbooks-have-a-true-hibernate-option)

**A handy (and free) hibernation widget/app:**
[Can Macs be put in hibernation voluntarily?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377/can-macs-be-put-in-hibernation-voluntarily)